# Can Outlook 2007 connect to a calendar in SharePoint 2013 with write privileges?

Tags: calendar, outlook

I have a shared calendar hosted on SharePoint 2013. If I use the connect to Outlook option with Outlook 2007 on a Windows 7 machine, the calendar links. I am not able to write to the calendar from the three computers I have tried so far. The one computer upon which I have Outlook 2013 installed works fine and can write to the calendar. Is this a limitation of Outlook 2007 or am I likely messing up the permissions?

My guess is that I need to wait to upgrade the rest of the computers to a later version of office. Please confirm. It will give me ammunition to use against our IT clan.

Comment: did you check this guy...i think that's your problem..http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/10155.aspx

Comment: The calendar connects fine. When I try to add anything to it, the entered item vanishes. On occassion it generates an error. I will paste it in here when next I encounter it. The write however always fails. The solution in the link above is a registry hack in another secondary link. The secondary link is dead.

Comment: Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x00000000) : 'MITAG-ENV - Calendar - Failed to copy one or more items because some are not compatible with SharePoint. The failed items were moved to your Local Failures folder and replaced with copies from the server. If you need assistance troubleshooting items in your Local Failures folder, a Help topic is available at the following address: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70300. For details, see the log file .' Seems that there may be an issue with lining up email addresses with contacts between groups.

Comment: Here is the problem discussed in detail with a repair: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84226725-c2db-4f48-87ca-eb3b5e7be34e/sharepointoutlook-interaction-issues-calendar-will-not-sync?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

Comment: I am awaiting local tech support to attempt the fixes I linked to above. I will report then they get around to helping me out.